# Search and replace from a list of replacements

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Using html import 2 plugin for wordpress, I've gathered a list of old file-paths and what they've been changed to.

Instead of bulking up my .htaccess with redirects, I was hoping there was a way to replace all the old links with the new ones.

For instance, i have a list:

```
oldlink1, newlink1
oldlink2, newlink2
oldlink3, newlink3
oldlink4, newlink4
```

and I want to replace every occurence of oldlink1 with newlink1. possible?

Comment: Whilst this question is on-topic for SO, you may find that the folks over at [wordpress.se] will be more familiar with the relevant schema.

Comment: Is this you are looking for `UPDATE table SET link=CASE WHEN link = 'oldlink1' THEN 'newlink1' ELSE 'oldlink1' END`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking about file and images paths in the post content? (1) Or are you asking about post permalinks to redirect the old .html URLs to new WordPress URLs without the .html suffix? (2)

1) For file image paths in post content, probably the easiest and most foolproof approach is to use a find/replace plugin that will provide a front end to the database so you don't run queries directly on the database.

Try http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/ With it, you can find/replace post content, post meta, comment content, etc.

> Search Regex adds a powerful set of search and replace functions to
>   WordPress. These go beyond the standard searching capabilities, and
>   allow you to search and replace almost any data stored on your site.
>   In addition to simple searches you have the full power of PHP's
>   regular expressions at your disposal.

2) For URL redirects, you can try http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/ which will allow a CSV import of URL redirects while logging 404s and redirects.

> Redirection is a WordPress plugin to manage 301 redirections and keep
>   track of 404 errors without requiring knowledge of Apache .htaccess
>   files.... This is particularly useful if you are migrating pages from
>   an old website, or are changing the directory of your WordPress
>   installation.

Answer (score 0):

With [this script](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) you can do a search & replace on your WordPress database. Just follow the instructions, and don't forget to remove the script after you're done.